Help understanding why bending moment is integral of shear
I am aware of the basics of Euler-Bernoulli beam theory but there is one thing that I have never understood satisfactorily. Where $M$ is the bending moment, and $V$ the shear force:
$$\frac{dM}{dx}=V\,\text{ or }M(x)=\int_0^x V(t)\,dt\qquad(*).$$
The explanation I see most widely posits an element of the beam and says that it is equilibrium and so the sum of the moments about a point is zero. For example, a small element with extents $x$ and $x+\Delta x$, and then it calculates the moment about the midpoint. Say from Figure 8.6.2 here.
Where we have $V(x+\Delta x)=V(x)+\Delta V=V+\Delta V$ and similar for $M(x+\Delta x)$, I understand where the terms $-V\cdot \Delta x/2$ and $-(V+\Delta V)\cdot \Delta x/2$ come from but for the life of me I don't understand how we can just include the moments at $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ into this sum:
$$-V\cdot \frac{\Delta x}{2}-(V+\Delta V)\cdot \frac{\Delta x}{2}-M+(M+\Delta M)=0.$$
Can someone either explain why this makes sense or perhaps come up with a different explanation of either of (*).
I can kind of feel that we are adding up all the moments in the element... but in my head $M$ is somehow already included via $-V\cdot \Delta x/2$ and $M+\Delta M$ comes into $-(V+\Delta V)\cdot \Delta x/2$

I still don't understand the conventional explanation given by r13 but their patience got me there in the end.
Definition: The bending moment at $x$ is the sum of all the moments about $x$ to the left of $x$.
There is a moment at $x=0$ called $M_A$. Cut the beam from $z=0$ to $z=x$ into elements of width $\Delta z$. Each element comprises a force of $w(z)\Delta z$ and the distance between the element and $x$ is $x-z$ to give a moment due to the element of:
$$\Delta M=w(z)\Delta z(x-z).$$
Sum these (passing to the integral):
$$
\begin{aligned}
M(x)&=M_A+\int_{z=0}^{z=x}w(z)(x-z)\,dz
\\ &=M_A+\int_0^x xw(z)\,dz-\int_0^xzw(z)\,dz
\\ &=M_A+x\int_0^xw(z)\,dx-\int_0^x zw(z)\,dx
\\&=M_A+x\cdot V(x)-\int_0^x zw(z)\,dz
\end{aligned}$$
Consider $\int_0^x z\,w(z)\,dz$ with parts using $u=z$ and $dv=w(z)\,dz$ so that $du=dz$ and $v=V(z)$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int zw(z)\,dz&=zV(z)-\int V(z)\,dz
\\ \implies\int_0^xzw(z)\,dz&=xV(x)-\int_0^xV(z)\,dz
\end{aligned}$$
Plugging into the above yields:
$$M(x)=M_A+\int_0^x V(z)\,dz\implies \frac{dM}{dx}=V(x),$$
as required.

Short answer to address your confusion is that moment $M(x)$ and transverse force $V(x)$ are basically independent quantities if you are looking just at a specific coordinate $x$ (e.g. there will be sections, where $M$ is zero and $V$ is not and also vice versa). In other words, there is no proportionality between these quantities $M(x)\propto V(x)$.
So your intuition that $M$ is somehow already included in the equilibrium using $-V\cdot \Delta x/2$ is not correct. (This would require the above proportionality to be true.)

Thank you Tomáš - I think my main confusion was actually not knowing the definition of the bending moment. Armed with that I am happy with my own solution.


Let $\Delta V = w_x*\Delta x$, and $\sum M_B = 0$
$- V_x*\Delta x -\Delta V*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - M_x + M_{x + \Delta x} = 0$
$- V_x*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - V_x*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - \Delta V*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - M_x + M_{x + \Delta x} = 0$
$-V_x*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - (V_x + \Delta V)*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - M_x + M_{x+\Delta x} = 0$
Note $M_{x+\Delta x} = M_x + \Delta M$
$-V_x*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - (V_x + \Delta V)*\frac{\Delta_x}{2} - M_x + (M_x+\Delta M) = 0$, which is identical to



Numerical Example:

$V_A = 1$, $\Delta V = 0.1$, $V_B = -1.1$
$M_B = M_A + V_A*(1) + \Delta V * (1/2) = 2.05$, or
$M_B - M_A - V_A*(1) - \Delta V * (1/2) = 0$
Since $\sum F = 0$ and $\sum M = 0$, the beam segment is in equilibrium.

Thank you for your effort but this does not address my confusion.

Let's expand something in your head, "−(V+ΔM)⋅Δx/2 = -V*Δx/2 - ΔM⋅Δx/2", do you see the mistake?

There was a typo down the bottom which has been fixed. But I have no problem with the derivation from the condition. My issue is writing down the condition. My confusion is in bold.

I think you meant " I don't understand how we can't just include the moments at x and x+Δx into this sum:". Please clarify.

It is correct as written. I do not understand why those two moments are included.

Assume member AB is a small segment cut from a loaded beam, do you agree that there would be a moment (Ma) and a shear force (Va) at where it is cut (jt A), and a shear force (Vb) and moment (Mb) at jt B?  Now wouldn't Vb = Va + internal load/force, and Mb = Ma +/- moment produced by Va and the internal load/force with respect to their distance to jt B?  Finally, what would result if we shift Mb to the right-hand side of the equal sign?

"Mb = Ma +/- moment produced by Va and the internal load/force with respect to their distance to jt B?" This I don't get.

Note that a beam is said in structural equilibrium only when the sum of forces = 0, and the sum of moments about any point on the beam = 0, with the effects from all forces and the end moments included.

Take the moment about the point$P=x+\Delta x/2$. I can see where the terms with $V$ come from but I don't understand how $M$ and $M+\Delta M$ are moments about $P$.

Use my diagram, and assume Mb is unknown, then write the equations in your head to solve for Mb. I may be able to understand your confusion.

If I try and do it myself I would startt with $M(x)$ is the sum of the moments to the left of $x$. So I have $M_A$. Then I want to add up/integrate $w(z)\Delta z\cdot (x-z)$ from $z=0$ to $z=x$... then this doesn't give what I hope and I consult the references and then I am confused.

WAIT. When I do my thing and integrate $z\cdot w(z)$ by parts it works out. Thanks for your patience, it got me there in the end!

Thanks for your help - I wrote it up. I was trying to figure this out for ages so thanks for your efforts.

Hope you truly get it - All forces, externally applied loads/forces, and the end reactions are all to be included when performing structural calculations.

I still don't understand the derivation in your answer but very happy with the derivation in mine. It proceeds directly from the definition of the bending moment to an integral where the integral of shear pops out.

In my example, I thought it would be understood that the span force "delta V" is the sum of w(x) over the segment length.

That wasn't a problem.
